# I want to disable drag for 500ms right after I drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So when I reorder a list, as soon as I drop the item, it will submit the positions to my backend code, and reorder the list on the backend. However, I ran into case that if I reorder really really fast, the list on the front end and backend after a while is not sync anymore. So I want to disable the drag right after I drop for a brief moment to avoid race condition.

```
function reorder(panelId, type){
    $(escapeClientId(panelId)).sortable({
        start: function(event, ui){
            ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            //submit my start and end position to the server
            //change the cursor to wait
            $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
            window.setTimeout(wait,600);                                    
        }
    });
    $(escapeClientId(panelId)).disableSelection();
}
function wait(){
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
}
```

As you can see, I change the cursor to `wait` cursor for 600ms, however even when the cursor is in the wait mode, it still allow the user to drag to reorder. Is there a way to completely disable the drag for a brief moment right after I drop?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-disable) and [enable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-enable) methods:

```
function reorder(panelId, type) {
    $(escapeClientId(panelId)).sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var panel = $(this), 
                body = $('body');

            panel.sortable("disable"); // Disable before submitting.
            body.css('cursor', 'wait');

            //submit my start and end position to the server
            //change the cursor to wait

            setTimeout(function () {
                body.css('cursor', 'default');
                panel.sortable("enable");
            }, 500); // Enable after 500 ms.
        }
    });
    $(escapeClientId(panelId)).disableSelection();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually have a similar approach, but one small issue is that if after I drop, and I reorder again really fast, my cursor never go back to default, it stay 'wait'. Can you help me with this issue as well?

Comment: @ThangPham I have updated the answer. Does that work better for you?

Comment: Thank you much for your help, but it still does not work. I still experience the same issue.

Comment: @ThangPham How about creating a CSS class where you set the cursor to wait: `.wait {cursor:wait}` and instead of `body.css('cursor', 'wait');` you use `body.addClass('wait');`. The same for `body.css('cursor', 'default');` you use `body.removeClass('wait');` instead. Does that work better?

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. the body have a style="cursor: auto", so that addClass and removeClass does have even show the cursor change.

Comment: @ThangPham Not even if you set `!important` like this: `.wait {cursor:wait !important}`? `!important` should override all matching styles that doesn't have `!important` set.